# Apache Logging for Performance

Tags: apache-2.2, performance

How can I log Apache's performance, i.e. how it takes to process a request? Similar to Tomcat's Valve concept, I'd like to add this logging on Apache to identify a bottleneck on my web app.

I'm using Apache and Tomcat via mod_jk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new log format that adds on response time.

```
LogFormat "\"%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t\" %V %m \"%U\" \"%q\" %{Content-Type}o %s %B %O %D" responsetime
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/responsetime.log" responsetime
```

The `%D` adds the response time in microseconds to the log. So you can always [make your own format](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html) for the access log just include the `%D` somewhere in the log

Comment: Add that to `httpd.conf`?

Comment: yep you can add it there or in a vhost entry